# LoopBack REST Middleware Modify Object Before Response

Tags: javascript, rest, express, loopbackjs, middleware

Just looking for a bit of theory here as going through the Strongloop documentation doesn't seem to help with my problem.

What I'd like to do is set up some middleware that can combine the requested object with other details; effectively what I have is objects that contain a user's ID and I'd like to have the server query the username and a couple of other details and collate the information into one object and respond with the new object.

So far I've literally just got some middleware running upon every API endpoint call and able to tell which route it is, but I don't know where to go from there. The REST response object is seemingly disconnected and I'm not sure how to access it. I'm not even sure it's been created at this point; is that where the `routes:after` phase might be used?

Many thanks in advance for any help, completely lost right now.

Comment: Wouldn't [operation hooks](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Operation+hooks) or [remote hooks](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Remote+hooks) be a better solution for your scenario? You could apply them in form of [mixin](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Defining+mixins), in case you need the same logic for multiple models.

Comment: Quite possibly, I'm doing a lot of learning at the moment. I'm currently collating the information on the client side after multiple API calls, which is working fine; for now it's likely I'll keep using that solution, but I'll look into using remote hooks for future developments. Thank you very much for the response, I'll definitely keep it in mind :)